# tftpd runs as root, despite explicit option "--user tftp"

Tags: process, users, tftp

I start my `tftp` server with the option `--user tftp` so that it runs as user `tftp` instead of root. However, `ps` shows that the process still runs as `root`

```
ps aux| grep tftp
root      2542  0.0  0.0  14856   324 ?        Ss   Jan11   0:00 /usr/sbin/in.tftpd --listen --user tftp -vvvvv -s -p --ipv4 /srv/tftp
```

`man tftpd` says, that:

```
--user username, -u username
    Specify  the username which tftpd will run as; the default is "nobody".  
    The user ID, group ID, and (if possible on the platform) the supple‐
    mentary group IDs will be set to the ones specified in the system 
    permission database for this username.
```

The user `tftp` exists on my system:

```
getent passwd | grep tftp
tftp:x:104:108:tftp daemon,,,:/srv/tftp:/bin/false
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the source code it would seem that the TFTP daemon only drops root privileges after a connection has been made.

**Edit**

In tftpd.c, at a certain point there's a

```
while (1) {
```

line, and at the bottom of the loop a child process is forked:

```
    /*
     * Now that we have read the request packet from the UDP
     * socket, we fork and go back to listening to the socket.
     */
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "fork: %m");
        exit(EX_OSERR);     /* Return to inetd, just in case */
    } else if (pid == 0)
        break;              /* Child exit, parent loop */
}

/* Child process: handle the actual request here */
```

In the code that follows, at a certain point the `setuid` call is done to drop root privileges

Comment: Can you reference the code that you saw this in?

Comment: @slm I hope this clarifies things

Comment: Yes thanks for taking the time to do that, it makes your answer much more meaningful!

Comment: @brm, I can indeed see new connection being established as user `tftp`. Any idea why the main deamon runs as `root` and not as `tftp` as well? Could this be a possible security problem?

Comment: Not sure, but I think root privileges are needed both to bind to a port number below 1024 and to do the setuid call